# What is the difference between "recursion" and "self-reference"?

Tags: terminology, recursion

The wikipedia articles are too advanced for me to understand, could someone give me a simple explanation please?

Comment: they're not really comparable terms. `recursion` refers to a function calling itself whereas `self-reference` refers to an object referencing itself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson would it be correct to say **recursion** calls itself; while **self-reference** refers to itself?

Comment: @skullpatrol essentially yes, but I feel like you are missing a fundamental difference - they cannot apply to the same type of thing.

Comment: By that I mean recursion is a special case of self-reference where the object being referred to (or called) is a function?

Comment: @Jake223 Is it correct to say that recursion is a special case of self-reference where the object being referred to (or called) is a function?

Comment: no. Self-reference refers to an *object* refetrencing itself [(see wikipedia's article on OOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) wheras recursion refers to a function, or method, not an object.

Comment: @Jake223 I know where you're coming from, but you could also say that a structure like a linked list is recursively defined (the definition has a base case and an recursive step), and there's no doubt that recursive functions are self-referential.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The context of the two terms is generally different.

Self referencing is in the context of data -- you have a data type that contains a reference to something of the same type.

Recursive is in the context of code -- you have a function or procedure that calls itself.

Example:

```
def factorial(n):
if n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Comment: Here are the two tag definitions on Stack Overflow: Recursion in computer science is a method of problem solving where the solution to a problem depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem. 

Self-reference is the ability of a program (or logical sentence) to refer to itself, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: And for tags, that seems about right.  You don't want to get into odd corner cases for a tag.  And it's probably about the level you want to think of now as well.

Answer (score 10):

Here's **a recursive function** (in C):

```
unsigned int fibonacci(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;

    if (n > 1)
        result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);

    return result;
}
```

Those two calls to `fibonacci()` inside the `fibonacci()` function are *recursive* calls.

Here's a **self-referential data structure**:

```
struct ListNode {
    char *data;
    struct ListNode *next;
}
```

The first element, `data`, is just a pointer to some sort of data. The second element, `next`, is a pointer to another `ListNode` structure. If you have two or more `ListNode` structures, you can set the `next` pointer of one to the address of another, and so on, and you then have a *linked list*. The structure is *self-referential* because the definition of the structure refers to itself. If you want to get really crazy, you could do this:

```
struct ListNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
node->data = someString;
node->next = node;
```

Now you've got a different kind of self-reference -- it's not just the definition of `struct ListNode` that refers to itself... you've set the `next` pointer of `node` to point to `node` itself. This is a circular linked list containing only one element. Cute, but not very useful. I mention it because it's a kind of self-reference, but it's not what people usually mean when they talk about self-referential data types.

Comment: Is it correct to say that recursion is a special case of self-reference where the object being referred to (or called) is a function?

Comment: Sure, you could say that a recursive call is a form of self reference. *Sometimes* the terms are nearly interchangeable, although not with respect to code. For example, most people would call "GNU" a "recursive acronym" because it stands for "GNU is Not Unix", but nobody would say that you were wrong if you called it a "self-referential acronym" instead.

Comment: @Caleb This is not a particularly good example, because List is a [recursive data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). So you are actually showing another example of recursion!

Comment: @AndresF. Can you give an example of a self-referential data structure that's not a recursive data type? Sources like [this](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps203/Spring99/supplements/javaLists/) and [this](http://careerride.com/C-self-referential-structure.aspx) use the term 'self-referential' for structures like linked lists while others use 'recursive'. If my answer fails to make a clear distinction between the terms, it's because the terms aren't exactly synonymous, but are very close in meaning.

Comment: @Caleb Oops, sorry. If you are saying they are very close in meaning, then we agree and I misunderstood you!

Answer (score 6):

Recursions, mostly useful ones, are expected to terminate after certain number of procedures in a sense that there is some initial value. unless you have a bad recursion that is useless.

Self References, are by themselves not exactly recursions but can be shown to have recursion in which case they generally never terminate.

Comment: If you define recursion as a construction being carried over a well-founded relation, then the fact a recursion does not terminate corresponds to an infinite decreasing sequence -- and therefore the self-referential "recursion" is not at all a recursion. This is much like how an algorithm is required to stop at some point.

Comment: What about this statement: "This sentence has five words." It's self-referential, but I don't see any nonterminating recursion. I also don't think recursion generally has to involve self-reference. If you compile a recursive C function into binary machine code, the machine code doesn't have any self-reference in it. I think the most you can say is that a terminating self-reference is one possible way of defining a recursion.

Comment: Yes, this my explanation is by no way perfect. I am just trying to simplify in case "OP is trying to interpret some self references as recurances." I no way mean self references are always non terminating recursions.

Comment: Is it correct to say that recursion is a special case of self-reference where the object being referred to (or called) is a function?

Answer (score 5):

**Recursion implies action.**

Examples:

- a function that calls itself
- a regex performing a * or + (ie repetitive) match

Technically, recursion should have an exit state but it's not a requirement.

**Self-reference implies structure.**

Ex. An instance method referencing the object it's attached to.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion requires something to process via calling the same process (often with different parameters). Even though you're often using functions and those functions call themselves, they technically enter a new step that just happens to look like the place they just came from.

Self-Reference means that something refers to itself. Classes can be self-referential by using `this`, but that's not meaningfully recursive.

Comment: So recursion requires a process via calling the same process, while self-reference is the "calling-of-itself"?

Comment: @skullpatrol - no. Self reference requires no calling what so ever.

Comment: So recursion requires a process via calling the same process, while self-reference is the "referencing-of-itself"?